# Where to set charset for submitting punchout html form to SAP OCI

Tags: forms, http, post, character-encoding

We need to HTTP post an html form back to a return URL specified by the OCI4 punchout system. We have to ensure that the form is encoded to the requested charset.

The question is, how best to ensure that the form is posted back in the correct charset?

HTTP header Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 ?

In the HTML head

In the Form accept-charset="utf-8" ?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt go into production yet, but will be soon.

For the resources, I have used OCI3 & 4 and Cxml as they are the only resource I have found on the net. What i have done is, I implemented a mock SAP system which primarly deals with PunchOut user. and then i implemented the Catalogue. It will allow you to do more testing in terms of OCI & cxml requirements.